# Null Reference exception using ADAL for acquiringtokenasync with resource and clientkey

Tags: c#, adal

I am hitting this null reference exception using [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet) with version:3.13.1.846, this doesn’t repro every time. Any ideas?

I have made sure that when calling `AcquireTokenAsync` on the `AuthenticationContext` as recommended in many [MS samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/intune-graph-apis#azure-ad-authentication-examples), [for example](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-connect-sample/blob/master/Microsoft-Graph-UWP-Connect-SDK/AuthenticationHelper.cs). Here's a link to the docs for [that method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet) and the [SecureClientSecret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.clientcredential.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_ClientCredential__ctor_System_String_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_ISecureClientSecret_) which is causing errors.

I am **not passing in a null value**

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.SecureClientSecret.ApplyTo(IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<SendTokenRequestAsync>d__65.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__55.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenForClientCommonAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Thanks,
Sara

Comment: Please add related code and explain more about your scenario to help reproduce the error .

Comment: This is a terrible question without any sample code.

Comment: Who on earth up voted this?!

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the moderators needs to have a word with themselves. The null reference occurs in MS' code not the poster's, they aren't passing in anything that's null etc.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a look over the source code for the `SecureClientSecret`

[SecureClientSecret](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/Platforms/net45/SecureClientSecret.cs)

I'm a bit confused as to what Microsoft are trying to do with their `ApplyTo` method, it looks a bit like the kind of pattern you see with `TryParse` and `out` params, populating a dictionary by reference.

More explicity, populating the dictionary value at `OAuthParameter.ClientSecret` (`'client_secret'`as that translates to), with the decrypted value of the `SecureString` stashed away inside `SecureClientSecret`.

Microsoft then clear down the private `SecureString` member, which means any further calls to `ApplyTo` are going to be met with an unhandled exception when we hit the first line:

```
var output = new char[secureString.Length];
```

`'secureString.Length'` is going to blow, the exception you'd expect, calling null.Length... `System.NullReferenceException`, something that we see happening in the stack trace.

If MS really need to clear away that member field after a single use for some reason that I don't understand at the moment, maybe they should consider making the class more robust.

Add an `IsApplied` method/property to the interface:

```
public interface ISecureClientSecret
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Writes SecureString to the dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameters"></param>
    void ApplyTo(IDictionary<string, string> parameters);

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates whether this <see cref="ISecureClientSecret"/> has already been applied.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if applied, otherwise <c>false</c></returns>
    bool IsApplied { get; };
}
```

Which could easily be implemented in the concrete class with:

```
public bool IsApplied => secureString == null;
```

Also, the `ApplyTo` method could make use of locking to prevent bad things happening with lots of calls:

```
public void ApplyTo(IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    secureLock.WaitOne();

    // We don't want to blow up if ApplyTo is called multiple times.
    if (IsApplied)
        return;

    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        ptr = Marshal.SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode(secureString);
        parameters[OAuthParameter.ClientSecret] = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode(ptr);

        if (secureString != null && !secureString.IsReadOnly())
            secureString.Clear();

        secureString = null;

        secureLock.Set();
    }            
}
```

Sticking a `AutoResetEvent` in as a member for the class.

```
private AutoResetEvent secureLock = new AutoResetEvent(true);
```

It would be great if one of the devs on this project could explain what they're trying to do as things seem a little convoluted as a newbie looking in.

**UPDATE**

As @Nan Yu previously said, I'd like to see the poster's calling code for the delegate that provides the auth. After playing around with my own version I'm wondering if making sure the vars related to the `SecureClientSecret` are scoped as low down as possible would get around the potential issues I discussed above.

I.e. Don't have any member/field references to the `SecureClientSecret`. Don't have any vars scoped outside the delegate itself either, as I think the underlying `SecureString` inside the `SecureClientSecret` object gets nulled and things don't work out well when you try to get another token passing in the original SecureString.

I believe this is essentially what @'Kevin ssssssss' was suggesting in their answer!

```
var delegateAuthProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token");
    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Resource, new ClientCredential(appClientId, new SecureClientSecret(appSecretSecure)));     

    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result.AccessToken); 
});
```

MS samples seem to recommend calling for a new token every time before making a Graph request, which personally seems like a waste to me, also if you end up making a lot of async calls (i.e `await Task.WhenAll(someTasks);`) you might end up with a race-like condition where every task wants to call for a token, and you'll get a lot of open sockets as the tasks get scheduled. Here's a snippet of some code I'd use when trying to deal with the token/delegate etc.

```
namespace GraphTestConsole
{
    using Microsoft.Graph;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
    using Nito.AsyncEx;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using System.Security;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class Program
    {
        private const string Resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

        private const string AppClientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";

        private static readonly SecureString AppClientSecretSecure = ToSecureString("YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET");

        private const string Tenant = "YOUR_TENANT.onmicrosoft.com";

        private static IGraphServiceClient _graphClient;

        private static string _token;

        private static DateTimeOffset _tokenExpiresOn = DateTime.Now;

        private static readonly AsyncLock _mutex = new AsyncLock();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsyncContext.Run(() => AsyncMain(AppClientId, AppClientSecretSecure, Tenant));
        }

        private static async Task AsyncMain(string appId, SecureString appSecretSecure, string tenant)
        {
            try
            {
                var upn = "YOUR_USER_UPN";
                _graphClient = GetGraphClient(appId, appSecretSecure, tenant);
                var user = await _graphClient.Users[upn].Request().Select("id").GetAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle the exception...
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        private static bool IsTokenInvalid => string.IsNullOrEmpty(_token) || (_tokenExpiresOn - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds <= 0;

        private static GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient(string appClientId, SecureString appSecretSecure, string tenant)
        {
            var delegateAuthProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                using (await _mutex.LockAsync())
                {
                    if (IsTokenInvalid)
                    {
                        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token");
                        var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Resource, new ClientCredential(appClientId, new SecureClientSecret(appSecretSecure)));

                        _token = result.AccessToken;
                        _tokenExpiresOn = result.ExpiresOn;
                    }

                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", _token);
                }
            });

            return new GraphServiceClient(delegateAuthProvider);
        }

        private static SecureString ToSecureString(IEnumerable<char> value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

            var secured = new SecureString();
            var charArray = value.ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
            {
                secured.AppendChar(charArray[i]);
            }

            secured.MakeReadOnly();
            return secured;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I still think the MS ADAL code is poorly written. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the SecureClientSecret class is intended to be single-use -- so if you construct a new one for every request, this problem should go away.